# How can I improve the accuracy of the CNN classifier in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I use batch_size = 1024 and the number of epochs = 100 . My classifier gives a maximum accuracy of 70% for my model. How can I improve the accuracy?

```
dr = 0.5 # dropout rate 
model = models.Sequential() 
model.add(Reshape(([1]+in_shp), input_shape=in_shp))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((0, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (1, 3),padding='valid', activation="relu", name="conv1",  kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',data_format="channels_first"))
model.add(Dropout(dr)) 
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((0, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(80, (2, 3), padding="valid", activation="relu", name="conv2",  kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',data_format="channels_first"))
model.add(Dropout(dr))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu',  kernel_initializer='he_normal', name="dense1")
model.add(Dropout(dr))
model.add(Dense( len(classes),  kernel_initializer='he_normal', name="dense2" ))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.add(Reshape([len(classes)]))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Comment: How much training data do you have?

Comment: traning set using a 128 samples rectangular windowing process. The
total dataset is roughly 500 MBytes stored as a python pickle file with complex
32 bit floating point samples. 

 (110000, 2, 128) [2, 128]

Comment: Well you can try a few things, but there isn't a straightforward answer so I am just putting it as a comment: 

- Make sure you input data is normalized (min-max or standard)

- Try different activations/optimizers/num_filters


- Plot your accuracy during training and see if it is converging on some minima or if it is still improving. You may just need to train longer

Comment: IMO you're abusing dropout. But without seeing your data, it's hard to tell and unlikely to be helpful to future users so I'm afraid this is [off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404075/how-should-we-handle-machine-learning-questions-asking-for-performance-improveme/404108). Why is your output layer a `Reshape` layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are list of suggested changes:

- You may drop ZeroPadding2D layer unless it's a must for images
  that you are handling
- On using multiple Conv2D() layer, start with small filters count then
  increase as you go. i.e. start with 32 then 64 then 128. Separate
  them by MaxPooling2D() with proper kernel size according to your
  case.
- add one more Dense() layer after Falttening() & before reaching last
  layer.

Check modified code with some

```
dr = 0.5 # dropout rate 
model = models.Sequential() 
model.add(Reshape(([1]+in_shp), input_shape=in_shp))
# You could drop the ZerpPadding2D as it adds rows and columns of zeros around image tensor
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((0, 2)))
# Start with lower filters count then increas as you go
model.add(Conv2D(32, (1, 3),padding='valid', activation="relu", name="conv1",  kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',data_format="channels_first"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2))
model.add(Dropout(dr)) 
#model.add(ZeroPadding2D((0, 2))) # no need 
# Increase filters count
model.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 3), padding="valid", activation="relu", name="conv2",  kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',data_format="channels_first"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 3), padding="valid", activation="relu", name="conv2",  kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',data_format="channels_first"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2))
model.add(Dropout(dr))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu',  kernel_initializer='he_normal', name="dense1")
model.add(Dropout(dr))
# Add one more Dense 
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu',  kernel_initializer='he_normal', name="dense1")
model.add(Dense( len(classes),  kernel_initializer='he_normal', name="dense2" ))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.add(Reshape([len(classes)]))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Finally, It obvious that you are using Dropout() extensively.

Last 2 cents:

- You need to pay attention to validation loss not accuracy only
- Try Transfer Learning, if you your data samples are limited.

Comment: What's the purpose of last `Reshape` layer?

Comment: @Frightera I just copied it from the provided coded. I was focusing on layers orders in the model.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but now I have a new problem "Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node conv2_14/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](max_pooling2d_34/Identity, conv2_14/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,32,1,124], [2,3,32,64]."